# Split a string with mixed characters and non-uniform delimiters

Tags: c#, arrays, substring

I have a program that executes the equivalent of the `df -k` command in Putty. I am having issues splitting the resultant string `lines` into substrings.

**Input**

This is an extract of the data i get when i run the program :

```
Filesystem           1024-blocks        Used   Available Capacity  Mounted on
rpool/ROOT/solaris-0    47185886    39055271     6723316    86%    /
rpool/ROOT/solaris-0/var    47185886      334036     6723316     5%    /var
/dev                           0           0           0     0%    /dev
/u01                   104857600    92783432    12074167    89%    /u01
proc                           0           0           0     0%    /proc
ctfs                           0           0           0     0%    /system/contract
mnttab                         0           0           0     0%    /etc/mnttab
swap                   333382928         536   333382392     1%    /system/volatile
```

**Expected**

Ideally I want to split each line above into substrings and cast these resultant substrings to a Model.
.. for example line 2 will have 6 substrings like this :

```
rpool/ROOT/solaris-0
47185886
39055271
6723316 
86%
/
```

... and each of these substrings will be cast to model `DiskStatistics` with properties :

```
    public String Filesystem { get; set; }
    public double Blocks { get; set; }

    public double Used { get; set; }

    public double Available { get; set; }

    public int Capacity { get; set; }

    public string Mount { get; set; }
```

I have tried to split one of the lines (in a sample console application) as below:

```
string line = "rpool/ROOT/solaris-0 47185886 39055271 6723316 86% /";
        Int32 count = 6;
        String[] separator = { ", ", "" };
        String[] strlist = line.Split(separator, count,
           StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        foreach (var s in strlist)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

but for the output I can only get:

```
rpool/ROOT/solaris-0 47185886 39055271 6723316 86% /
```

I have observed the spaces (delimiters) between each pair of substrings in the original data is also not uniform.

This is how I'm getting the data in the original program:

```
using (SshClient ssh = new SshClient("+ server IP + ",
            "+ username +", "+ password +"))
            {
               ssh.Connect();
               var result = ssh.RunCommand("df -k");
               var rss = result.Result;
               string[] lines = rss.Split('\n');
               var  stats = new List<DiskStatistics>();

               foreach (var line in lines)
               {

                //Split each line in lines into 6 substrings 
               //Cast each substring (up to 6 in each line that is split) to Model DiskStatistics

                }

            }
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: `String[] separator = { ", ", "" };` I don't get it - why would you use such separators if they are not even present in the input?

Comment: @BartoszKP i got it wrong there. Im not even sure how to achieve my intent with that kind of method. My problem lies in that the space delimiters in my data are not uniform. Some substrings have 3 spaces that delimit them , some have 4 and so forth . And that implementation https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/string-split-method-in-c-sharp-with-examples/ is the closest i have so far to achieve my objective ..

Comment: `String[] separator = { " " }; String[] strlist = line.Split(separator, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);`

Comment: @Golide What Retired Ninja said is the solution to the thing you describe, but it still doesn't match your code - there are no multiple separators in `line` - every entry is surrounded by single spaces. So it's still unclear what did you want to show there.

Comment: @BartoszKP yes true , i have just verified. Its splitting well. I had pasted the line incorrectly. I have since amended and tested for all lines in the dataset

Comment: @Golide Please kindly edit the question and restate what is your problem at this point (or close/autoanswer if it's solved). You don't need to put "EDIT" headers - just fix the post as a whole to be clear on your issue.

Answer (score -1):

If you know that whitespace is your delimiter, but the amount of spaces used is unknown, one option is to use `Match` class with the Regex library in C#:

Example:

```
foreach (var line in lines)
{
  // Creates an array of results that are non-whitespace.
  var m = Regex.Match(line, @"(\S+)"); 

  for (int i = 1; i <= m.Groups.Count; i++)
  {
    Console.WriteLine($"{m.Groups[i].Value}");
  }
}
```

Bonus Benefit: It will also handle cases where the user used tabs instead of spaces!